# ansible tower reports : stdout capture is missing

Tags: ansible, stdout, ansible-tower

How to fix the error of stdout capture being missing. I am scheduling couple of tasks, initially they are running fine after couple of iteration it is throwing this error.

[image]

Comment: What did Ansible support say?

Comment: I haven't spoken to Ansible support yet. I was thinking this would be very trivial and have an easy fix. I will speak to Ansible support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached out Ansible Support and apparently they acknowledged that the Tower Version which I was then using [ 2.1.3 ] had some bugs and they recommended to upgrade to 2.1.4 solved the issue.

**Update :** More to it, I was using Instance size of t2.micro - which they recommended to use an instance with higher Memory Capacity - running that with m3.medium did the trick.

Ansible Tower 2.1.4 - [Download Link](http://releases.ansible.com/ansible-tower/setup/ansible-tower-setup-2.1.4.tar.gz)

Answer (score 0):

"stdout capture missing" typically means the Tower job failed before it got properly started. That can happen with gross misconfiguration or yml format issues. I think I've seen it with bad job template vars too.

The job info page should explain what happened. If not, you can hit up the API: `/api/v1/jobs/123/`

Comment: I have spoken to Ansible Support and they are currently looking at my sosreport. I get the same error even if I do a straight forward - SCM GIT Update, so I am thinking there is somewhere - not just with playbooks

Comment: make sure to answer your own question when you figure it out- that way it'll help others in the future.

`sudo servicectl status` may show a service that isn't running (though that may not help in Tower 2.x).